# scrolling overlay div without scrolling entire page

Tags: html, css

I have a main page with some content on it.  I then have a modal that pops up which is longer than the screen itself so I have to scroll to see it.  What do I need to do to my CSS to make only the modal `div` scroll instead of the whole page?

Here is the CSS for the modal

```
#overlay {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid #A17E13;
    height:auto;
    text-align:left;
    z-index: 1000; 
}
#overlay div {
    background-color:#FCFBEC;
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<html><body>
    <div>main page</div>
    <div id="overlay">
    <div>
        <div>
             <asp:Label ID="test">Text for modal here</asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: where is the rest of your code. With what you show it is impossible to see your structure.

Comment: that's it.  The structure is simple the main div and then a separate div for the modal.

Comment: can you limit your modal to be only the size of the screen and no larger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

has the entire page not to be scrollable except of the modal div? if so can you try position:fixed; on the page. the modal has to be outside with position:absolute;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#overlay {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    position: fixed;
    left: 45%;
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid #A17E13;
    height:900px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:orange;
}
.scroller {
    height:3000px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay">
        this is not moving
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="scroller">
             <asp:Label ID="test">This is moving if big enough</asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RL6v8/)